# How to know which devices are mapped to a memory range in Win 7

Tags: windows-7, memory

I an having issues with my Wireless card on Win 7 - the issue being that the memory range it maps to conflicts with "something else".

Is there any easy way of knowing what that "something else" is?

For example, would I be able to query the "system database" to find out which devices map to that memory location etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, I was pretty sure we were done with these kinds of conflicts about 15 years ago.

You can view memory mappings by opening the device manager, clicking view, and then resources by type.  From there, open up the tree in the memory area.

Comment: Wow, you learn something every day.

Comment: Yup - the wireless adapter thingy is pretty messed up. I just did a fresh Win 7 installation and the thing just does not seem to register - as if it were not plugged in at all! Is there some utility that will allow me to see devices physically connected, regardless of whether they have a driver or not?

Comment: Yeah... device manager.